# Best way to deal with mysql tables that are constantly being updated

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a scenario that I cant figure out the best way to properly deal with. I have a mysql database with many tables that stores configuration information for many devices around the world. There is a script that is run at frequent intervals to look for changes, track state, and various other things relevant to these devices.

The data drives a front-end application that is used for management of said devices. My question is how do I properly deal with updating the database all the time. So at present I write all the data to temp tables and then truncate/select * into the active tables.

I know this is absolutely horrible and it causes many different issues which are a real pain. I am certain there must be a better way but I cant find one. Can anyone suggest something that would be more efficient. These tables are relatively small so I can get away with above method. ( less than 2k of rows per table)

What would be nice is if I could figure out how to update only things that have changed and anything new. I just cant figure out how to swing that one. Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

mysql version:
mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.1.67
MyISAM ( probably should not be using this either... ?)

Is there some way I could try and use a timestamp or something along those lines...

UPDATE:
I did not give enough data here, so my fault. Let me try to give some kind of better detail.

I have a simple table that stores fields like: (greatly simplifying here)

hostname,ip,state,policy,location.

I have a script that runs about every 10 mins to capture all of this and more to dump into mysql. The problem is that when I truncate there are times when a user may be trying to use the front end application and the table is not populated yet. I am trying to come up with a better way to deal with this.

Comment: There is such little information here that it is unclear what you're asking. Please share some code, schema, and examples of your data.

Comment: I am looking for a suggestion on how to deal with updating tables when the data may not have changed but at the same time inserting new data. So not looking for anyone to give me code examples really , more just an idea.... For the sake of simplicity let me try to use this as an example. I have a table that stores state,ip,hostname, and policy fields. The fields policy or state can change at any time and need to be dealt with on a change.

Comment: This doesn't seem to be an SQL / mySQL problem at all, nor actually anything specific to PHP.  The problem appears to be about the front end application knowing what changes to apply.  If it knew that, it could just perform the appropriate `INSERT` and `UPDATE` statements on the main tables.  In the `UPDATE` case, it would be OK to just update all non-PK columns.

Comment: How the application might or should track any of that depends on a lot of things, significantly including the application style (local program vs. web application) and usage model (especially whether it must accommodate many simultaneous users accessing the same database).

Comment: I wonder if it would make more sense to use a timestamp and allow for duplicate rows (since the data set is so small) . Then I can always look for most recent data and at some point get rid of older entries.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two things: MyISAM probably isn't the best bet for your tables. Writing to MyIASM locks the whole table. An engine like InnoDB will allow for row-level locking, so only rows getting affected will be locked during UPDATES and INSERTS. Of course switching to this may not be straightforward. MyIASM has its uses. Its quick, low-overhead, generally pretty good for data warehousing.

Next look into using message busses, i.e. [RabbitMQ](http://www.rabbitmq.com/features.html).  These act as buffers for large datastreams which you can import into your database in batches rather In real time. As your app scales these things will become more and more necessary.

Comment: ah that is perfect thanks ! So I was already going to make a change which would be updates/inserts with no truncate. However, there was still something missing a message buffers looks like it could do the trick. thanks!!